# Expression for random numbers without duplicates

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, random

Using only the QGIS field calculator, how to create an expression that generates random numbers without duplicates?

rand (1,10) and randf (1,10) generate random numbers but could be repeated in a set of 10 records.

this expression generates 10 random numbers without duplicates

```
array_distinct (array_agg (expression: = rand (1,10))
```

but it's an array I need a single number for each record.

Comment: This more of a [so] question than GIS SE, but should be simple enough to create a list with 10 elements and use a random generator to choose an integer in the range [0...len(l)-1], then destructively read that element from the list. If len(1) == 1, just return the last element and reinitialize the list.

Comment: Does creating a custom python function counts?

Comment: What is your use case? And you mean you need a column with random numbers that are unique for each feature?

Comment: It could be very useful regardless of this case, thanks Alexandre Neto

Comment: my use case is as follows:
I have a table with 1000 records, I wish I could split the records into 10 groups and insert a unique random number from 1 to 100.

Exactly, I need a column with unique random numbers for each function!
thanks spatialthoughts

Comment: I would add a random number from 1 to 1000 in a column,  order that, then do a loop giving 1,2,3... Until 10. And start back at 1 again.

Comment: I don't want to go OT, so I'm looking for a way to generate random numbers without duplication.
for my use case another question would be needed.

Comment: @pigreco - How about an expression like: `array_get(array_distinct(array_agg (rand(0, count($id)))), $id)`

Comment: @Joseph 
thank you, interesting; but it doesn't populate all the records because the random numbers (rand (0, count ($ id)) don't follow $ id, here are two examples that always vary:
array_length (array_distinct (array_agg (rand (0, count ($ id))))) || '-' || count ($ id) → 65-100
array_length (array_distinct (array_agg (rand (0, count ($ id))))) || '-' || count ($ id) → 12-20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@AlexandreNeto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/6191/alexandre-neto) mentioned, you could create a custom python function in the Field Calculator which creates a range  list of values based on the feature count of your active layer. The list is then shuffled and you can extract a unique id value randomly.

You could use something like the following script:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import random

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
ids = list(range(1, layer.featureCount() + 1))
random.shuffle(ids)

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def random_id(value, feature, parent):
    return ids[value]
```

And then use the following as the expression:

```
random_id($id)
```

---

Note: You must click the `Save and Load Functions` button in the *Function Editor* **before** using it on other layers. This is because defining the active layer and creating the list of unique values based on its features count is outside the function in order to avoid re-creating the list each time for each row.

Comment: Joseph - I tried to use the function, here are my results:
random_id ($id) on a shapefile of 100 features gives me an error (list index out of range)

Comment: @pigreco - Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: Joseph - I did the test in QGIS 3.4.6.
(in 3.6 and 3.7 master it works !!!)
thank you

Comment: @pigreco - Most welcome, glad it works :)